# Macro runs on wrong tab. How can I specify it to only run on the tab I specify?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the code - it works fine.  Except i just ran it and it executed on the wrong tab meaning i lost a bunch of data.  How can I specify it to only to ever run on the tab called "Form Responses 1"?

```
    /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function DragDownRefresh() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B10:l10').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('B10:l2002'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B10:l2002').activate();
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Here `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` you define to use the active sheet. Check out [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function DragDownRefresh() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();    
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    sheet.getRange('B10:l10').activate();
    sheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('B10:l2002'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
    sheet.getRange('B10:l2002').activate();
    };
```